# Does disabling the pin bias not apply an internal resistor or disconnect the pins altogether?

Tags: linux-kernel, i2c

I'm looking at a device-tree configuration for an I2C line.  It was previously `bias-disable` for an I2C that wasn't working and my natural inclination is to test with `bias-pull-up` (but there are external 4k pull-up resistors).  My question is, what does `bias-disable` really mean?

**Does disabling the pin bias not apply an internal resistor or disconnect the pins altogether?**

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/brcm,bcm11351-pinctrl.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Seems like the correct answer is:

> disabling the pin bias not apply an internal resistor

Details are below.

### Investigation

From documentation for pinctrl bindings (`Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/pinctrl-bindings.txt`):

> `bias-pull-up`, `-down` and `-pin-default` take as optional argument on hardware supporting it the pull strength in Ohm. `bias-disable` will disable the pull.

If documentation is not sufficient, it's time to look into the code.

In `drivers/pinctrl/pinconf-generic.c`:

```c
static const struct pinconf_generic_params dt_params[] = {
    { "bias-disable", PIN_CONFIG_BIAS_DISABLE, 0 },
```

In `include/linux/pinctrl/pinconf-generic.h`:

```c
/**
 * enum pin_config_param - possible pin configuration parameters
 * @PIN_CONFIG_BIAS_DISABLE: disable any pin bias on the pin, a
 *  transition from say pull-up to pull-down implies that you disable
 *  pull-up in the process, this setting disables all biasing.
```

Next thing you can do is to look how exactly this `PIN_CONFIG_BIAS_DISABLE` is handled in drivers for your particular hardware. In your case I believe the driver resides at `drivers/pinctrl/bcm/pinctrl-bcm281xx.c`.

Look [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pinctrl/bcm/pinctrl-bcm281xx.c#L1251) (`bcm281xx_i2c_pin_update()` function):

```c
    case PIN_CONFIG_BIAS_DISABLE:
        bcm281xx_pin_update(val, mask, 0,
            BCM281XX_PIN_SHIFT(I2C, PULL_UP_STR),
            BCM281XX_PIN_MASK(I2C, PULL_UP_STR));
        break;
```

As you can see, 3rd parameter to `bcm281xx_pin_update()` (which is `value`) is 0. So the next values will be used to set the corresponding register:

```c
#define BCM281XX_I2C_PIN_REG_PULL_UP_STR_MASK   0x0070
#define BCM281XX_I2C_PIN_REG_PULL_UP_STR_SHIFT  4
```

Now, having datasheet or TRM for BCM281XX, you should be able to figure out the exact register, which is being set with 0, and from that datasheet you can figure out what is exactly going on when setting it to 0. Unfortunately, I couldn't find this datasheet on internet, so I can only assume that this `"bias-disable"` just disconnects pull-up and pull-down internal resistors in your SoC. But still, SoC documentation should be used to say it for sure.

Also, maybe it can be useful: here is the first commit adding this driver: [54b1aa5a5b16](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=54b1aa5a5b166f3e0863adde6cf9d14442fa244c).